# Why does "Driver Software Installation" take so long Win7

Tags: windows-7, drivers

When I plug some devices into my computer they go through the Windows "Driver Software Installation" phase.

These devices were previously plugged into my computer and drivers installed.

Why does this still happen and takes much longer than before?

Comment: If its usb based, then they'll go through that for each different USB port...as for being longer, then one part of the installation phase is checking with MS's servers for a later driver...its likely that part that is slower, as its network related.

Comment: Ok, so if I use the same USB port it shouldn't be a problem?